# Converting an int to a char in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, int, type-conversion

I'm trying to add an int to a char array. My (broken) code is as follows,

```
string[i] = (char) number;
```

with `i` being some int index of the array and `number` is some integer number. Actually, while typing this out I noticed another problem that would occur if the number is more than one digit, so if you have some answer to that problem as well that would be fantastic!

Comment: What are you expecting to get into `string[i]`? Let's suppose `number` contains 8; what do you expect in `string[i]`?  What about if `number` contains 264?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, If `number` contains 8, I would expect '8' to be in `string[i]`. I actually didn't consider the case of numbers with multiple digits. I suppose I will have to restrict `number` to be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 9.

Comment: You say `'8'` in your comment, meaning the ASCII character `8`? ASCII `8` is integer value `56`. Do you want printable ASCII `8` or integer `8`?

Comment: Staring at [this chart](http://www.asciitable.com) and debugging your code to see the value of `number` will probably explain a *lot* regarding the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Are you trying to get the visual representation for a number, or are you trying to down-cast a value to a narrower field and account for overflow, etc?

Comment: @Macattack, correct. However, would there be any way to take the integer value 8 and convert it to ASCII `8`? I suppose I could add 48 to the int each time, but then what?

Comment: @Rohan: If you add `48`, nobody reading your code will know why you used that particular number. Add `'0'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the revised requirement to get digit `'0'` into `string[i]` if `number == 0`, and similarly for values of `number` between `1` and `9`, then you need to add `'0'` to the number:

```
assert(number >= 0 && number <= 9);
string[i] = number + '0';
```

The converse transform is used to convert a digit character back to the corresponding number:

```
assert(isdigit(c));

int value = c - '0';
```

Comment: it's worth noting that this works because C requires the representations for `'0'` .. `'9'` to be contiguous. This method doesn't necessarily work for letters, which are not required to be contiguous; for example, `'a' + 25` is not necessarily `'z'` (though it is in ASCII).

Comment: @KeithThompson why is it that way? It seems to me that when I do `char letter = 'a'` and then `letter++;`, it continuously increments the ASCII value so that `a + 25` would be `'z'`.

Comment: @Rohan: Yes, `'a' + 25 == 'z'` -- *for your implementation*. My point is that the C standard doesn't guarantee that. In particular, it's not true for systems using ECBDIC rather than ASCII. C *does* guarantee that `'0' + 9 == '9'` are contiguous (but not that `'0' == 48`).

Comment: For most systems, including systems using Unicode and the ISO 8859 code sets, then for the unaccented Latin alphabet, you can `assert('z' - 'a' == 25);`, but in EBCDIC, which is found primarily on IBM mainframes or in systems connecting to those, there are gaps in the alphabet (so 'a'..'i' are contiguous (0x81..0x89), and 'j'..'r' are contiguous (0x91..0x99), and 's'..'z' are contiguous (0xA2..0xA9)).  There are valid non-alphabetic characters in the gaps between these ranges. See [EBCDIC](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) at Wikipedia for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert a single digit to a number character you can use

```
string[i] = (char) (number+'0');
```

Of course you should check if the int value is between 0 and 9. If you have arbitrary numbers and you want to convert them to a string, you should use `snprintf`, but of course, then you can't squeeze it in a char aynmore, because each char represents a single digit.

If you create the digit representation by doing it manually, you should not forget that a C string requires a `\0` byte at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use sprintf().

```
sprintf(string,'%d',number);
```

I believe.

EDIT: to answer the second part of your question, you're casting an integer to a character, which only holds one digit, as it were.  You'd want to put it in a char* or an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

use asprintf :

```
char *x;
int size = asprintf(&x, "%d", number);
free(x);
```

is better because you don't have to allocate memory. is done by asprintf

Comment: Apart from being a non-standard GNU extension, the idea is correct.